# Can you use Kog'maw as a shield after he dies?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can Kog'maw, after having his health be dropped to zero, be used as a living shield for the remainder of time he has left before he blows up to block skills like Dark Binding from Morgana?

Answer (score 14):

No, he is untargetable so the enemy cannot attack him and their skills will fly through him.